# Perl sub inside a sub

Tags: perl

I want to have a sub inside another sub,

```
sub a {
    sub b {
    }
}
```

I want to create a new instance of `sub b` for every call to `sub a`. Is there a way to do this in Perl?

When I run the code above and print the address of `sub b` in `sub a` I always get the same address for `sub b` like

```
sub a {
    print \&b;
    sub b{
    }
}
```

[This link on Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=801229) says that we can do this, but I always see the same address for `sub b`.

Is there a way to create a new instance of `sub b` for every call to `sub a`?

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve with multiple instances of the same subroutine. I am certain that Perl has a solution for you, but perhaps not in the fashion you have chosen

Answer (score 12):

```
sub a {
    sub b{
    }
}
```

is basically the same as:

```
sub a {

}
sub b{
}
```

because named subroutines live in the symbol table hence they are global.
you will need to return a reference to a subroutine.

Comment: Are they "the same" in the sense of the variable scopes each can access?

Answer (score 8):

Named subroutines are only created once. You need to return an anonymous subroutine reference something like this:

```
sub a {
    my $counter = 1;
    return sub {
        return $counter++;
    }
}

my $c1 = a();
my $c2 = a();

# different references
print "c1 = $c1, c2 = $c2\n";

# each has a different counter
print "c1 ", $c1->(), "\n";
print "c1 ", $c1->(), "\n";
print "c2 ", $c2->(), "\n";
print "c2 ", $c2->(), "\n";
```

Comment: This won't create a new instance of the anonymous subroutine. Only the closure is different

Comment: But this is a better example of a closure than anything else

Comment: @Borodin: In formal computer science, a "closure" consists of a "subroutine" (or "procedure" or "function") plus an environment; but since few programming languages allow the programmer to make any serious distinction between a closure and its subroutine, or between a subroutine that closes over its lexical environment and one that doesn't, it's quite normal for programmers in a given language to refer to an entire closure as a "subroutine" (or "function" or whatnot, depending on the language). What's more, most languages' official definitions/standards do the same thing.

Comment: @ruakh: I agree with you partially, but have never seen a subroutine plus its upvalues referred to so casually. Can you offer a citation? What [@adrianh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13165/adrianh) said, and what I was hoping to correct, is *"Named subroutines are only created once. You need to return an anonymous subroutine"*.

Comment: @vol7ron: I don't understand. This solution works best as an example of closures, or this solution is the best example of closures?

Comment: @Borodin: given the question, this is a better answer for a Perl closure (keeping the subroutine instanced), rather than creating a new instance, as the question asked.  Though, as you wrote, I too was unclear about was being asked and would like a little more explanation from MojoUser.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a reference to an anonymous sub:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub a
{
    my($b) = @_;
    my $subref = sub { my($a) = @_; print "a = $a; b = $b\n"; return $a + $b; };
    &$subref(3);
    return $subref;
}

my $sub1 = a(10);
my $a10  = &$sub1(19);
my $sub2 = a(20);
my $a20  = &$sub2(20);
print "a10 = $a10; a20 = $a20; sub1 = $sub1; sub2 = $sub2\n";
```

Sample output:

```
a = 3; b = 10
a = 19; b = 10
a = 3; b = 20
a = 20; b = 20
a10 = 29; a20 = 40; sub1 = CODE(0x7ffc3c002eb8); sub2 = CODE(0x7ffc3c032eb8)
```

Comment: -1 for multiple bad practice Perl coding and appalling identifiers

Comment: @Borodin: could you explain that? I am not noticing the bad practice you're speaking of; though, I do agree the variable naming could be improved

Comment: @vol7ron: you should *never* use `$a` or `$b` as identifiers because they are built-in names used by the `sort` operator. And the use of `&` to call subroutines has been wrong for a very long time

Comment: @Borodin: yes, that is true about `$a` and `$b` but the OP used that, so to keep it in reference to the question, I think it'd be acceptable here.  And I don't think I've ever heard that using `&` is wrong.  Programmers should just know that `&foo` is not the same as `&foo()` or `foo()`, but I think he's using it correctly in the above.

Answer (score 3):

```
sub a {
    my $b = sub {
    };
    print \&$b;
}
```

or glob it:

```
sub a {
    local *b = sub {
    };
    print \&b;
}
```

Comment: +1, though I think `\&$b` is a pretty complicated way to spell `$b`. :-P

Comment: I agree, but didn't want to confuse